# Alexa skill developed in node.js doesn't display any card

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-sdk-nodejs

Alexa skill developed in node.js doesn't display any card in the home page of the Alexa app, for Simple or Standard Card type with npm package 'alexa-sdk' . It seems there's an issue in the 'Alexa-sdk' package's response.js file.
I used the following method

```
'THREE_D_QuestionIntent': function() {

    let reply = " Here’s a list"
    let speechOutput = reply;
    let repromptSpeech = "Question";
    let cardTitle = resultCardTitle;
    let cardContent = "Result is ";
    let imageObj = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/visitmadison/HTML/shape.png";

    console.log(speechOutput);

    this.emit(':askWithCard', speechOutput, repromptSpeech, cardTitle, cardContent, imageObj);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Standard Alexa cards with image you have include an image object with `smallImageUrl` and `largeImageUrl` properties. `smallImageUrl` and `largeImageUrl` are the URLs of a small and large version of the image to display.

For example, the response JSON will have:

```
...
"card": {
      "type": "Standard",
      "title": "Ordering a Car",
      "text": "Your ride is on the way",
      "image": {
        "smallImageUrl": "https://carfu.com/resources/card-images/race-car-small.png",
        "largeImageUrl": "https://carfu.com/resources/card-images/race-car-large.png"
      }
    }
...
```

Update your code with an image object having both `smallImageUrl` and `largeImageUrl`

```
var speechOutput = 'your speech here';
var repromptSpeech = 'your re prompt here';
var cardTitle = 'card title here';
var cardContent = 'card content here';
var imageObj = {
   "smallImageUrl": "https://carfu.com/resources/card-images/race-car-small.png",
   "largeImageUrl": "https://carfu.com/resources/card-images/race-car-large.png"
};
this.emit(':askWithCard', speechOutput, repromptSpeech, cardTitle, cardContent, imageObj);
```

More about Standard Card [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/include-a-card-in-your-skills-response.html#create-a-home-card-to-display-text-and-an-image)

Card images must meet certain conditions like:

1. [Image Format and Size](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/include-a-card-in-your-skills-response.html#image_size)
2. [Hosting the Images](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/include-a-card-in-your-skills-response.html#image_hosting)

Comment: The response doesn't contain the card type only, imageObj wasn't the issue 
{
 "body": {
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
   "outputSpeech": {
    "type": "SSML",
    "ssml": "<speak> You said sweaty people are your thing.</speak>"
   },
   "reprompt": {
    "outputSpeech": {
     "type": "SSML",
     "ssml": "<speak> You can also see the list in your Alexa app. Do you want this list emailed to you? </speak>"
    }
   },
   "shouldEndSession": false
  },
  "sessionAttributes": {},
  "userAgent": "ask-nodejs/1.0.25 Node/v6.10.3"
 }
}

Comment: Check whether you card meet those conditions.